# bash - problems reading text file and printing line by line

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am having problems printing each line from my output list.

The contents look like this:

My text file, if you cat it has a string that looks like this:

```
YYYYMMDD - ABCD B-1B DCI (Foo) Meeting Minutes - Template
```

However my output is printing out each item as a line, like this:

```
I want to print this line:YYYYMMDD
I want to print this line:-
I want to print this line:ABCD
I want to print this line:B-1B
I want to print this line:DCI
I want to print this line:(Foo)
I want to print this line:Meeting
I want to print this line:Minutes
I want to print this line:-
I want to print this line:Template
```

How do I fix this so that I print out each string?

Here is my code:

```
    PGLIST="pglist.lst";
    PGS=`cat $PGLIST`;

    #Create a list from executing this script
    ./confluence.sh $CMD_PGLIST $CMD_SPACE "$1" > "$PGLIST"

    #Print out lines
    for line in $PGS; do
        echo "I want to print this line:$line"
    done
```

Comment: set `IFS=$'\n'` before your loop

Comment: got it to work. thanks. however, i got an extra print line `I want to print this line:   `. How do i get rid of that?